# Magnetic focusing of microfocus X-Ray tube

Tags: magnetic-fields, x-rays

I've got this Russian X-Ray tube - [BS-5](http://3.14.by/en/read/first-xray). It has specified focus spot size of $\approx 6~\mathrm{\mu m}$.

It works, but I've seen brief mentions that in order to reach specified $6~\mathrm{\mu m}$ spot size one should use magnetic focusing. Does anyone have any guideline/links on how this magnetic focusing should be applied in principle to the tubes of this shape/type?

[image]

Comment: I think this may not be getting attention because it's kind of unclear. Your say "this shape/type" but the photo is kind of small. Perhaps include a diagram.

Comment: This is a **dangerous and nasty thing to play with - both high voltage and X-rays can hurt you!** I don't see any radiation shielding in this photo, how are you protecting yourself? There are two kinds of magnetic lenses for focusing, 1) a pair of magnetic quadrupole lenses, and 2) a single solenoid lens. The energy and magnetic rigidity of the electrons is in the same ballpark as a high-end scanning electron microscope (SEM), so reading up on SEM optics will help they use both kinds. It's really tricky to align and focus - how will you know the quality of the focused spot?

Comment: ...and speaking of lens design, [here's a question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/286495/83380) with no answers yet!

Comment: @BarsMonster, do the resources given in my answer help, or no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking around on the internet a bit, I found several resources that may be of interest.

- A patent, online [here](https://www.google.com/patents/US3374355), that is for the magnetic focusing of x-ray tubes. It includes a nice description, as well as references and diagrams. According to the description,

> A primary object of the invention resides in the provi sion [sic] of an improved method f0. [sic] the reduction of the focal spot size within an X-ray tube which is adapted to deliver an X-ray burst of extremely short time duration.

This seems to be exactly what you are looking for. It also includes a couple of diagrams showing the x-ray tube this system is intended for, and I'm not an expert but it doesn't look too different from what you've got. So that may be of assistance.

- Another patent, online [here](https://www.google.com/patents/US9142382), describes a magnetic focusing lens that might be somewhat related to what you are looking at.
- [This paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4008761/) is about electrostatic focusing, not magnetic focusing, but may also be useful in providing other methods to do what you want to do.
- Finally, [this book excerpt](https://books.google.com/books?id=MyVHpqi1SXwC&pg=PT476&lpg=PT476&dq=magnetic+focusing+x-rays+to+reduce+spot+size&source=bl&ots=TbsheSKrih&sig=ETZvNhhTDux5wWznzFTcoo5Lg-Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCjP-75JLQAhWm3YMKHbUiC9gQ6AEIODAH#v=onepage&q=magnetic%20focusing%20x-rays%20to%20reduce%20spot%20size&f=false) may be useful; it goes more in depth on magnetic focusing lenses.

Hope this helps! I'll be adding more resources as I find them.